# Is there a central source for real estate shape files for across the US?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa

Is there a central source for shape files for real estate across the US.  Most counties will provide shape files via the county appraisal district.  But there are over 3,000 to request.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! This may be a better question for OpenData. I did find a resource that shows which regions have parcel data available for download: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4fa0b020ee4c4747be56cfbc02108716

Comment: If you are able to pay, companies such as CoreLogic have parcel data products.

Comment: I think if you add "parcel" to your search, you'll find better results. For example, this thread from the GIS site, from where your question was migrated: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/44831/112869

Answer (score 1):

No, realtors and real estate professionals typically covet their data and are very unwilling to share. To that point, my experience with the industry allows me to say that if these shapefiles did exist, they would be outdated almost immediately because people in the industry create new neighborhoods to make sales.
To your question, what is in a real estate shapefile? Neighborhoods? Zoning?

[Zillow has neighborhood boundaries](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) which is about the closest thing you are going to find.